# If I use the property of an object as the key in Memory Cache, will that object still be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, garbage-collection, memorycache

Imagine you have an object like User, where one property is UserName. Say you want to use C# MemoryCache to store some information about that user, and use the UserName string property as the key in the cache.

Will this prevent garbage collection of the User object?

Comment: We will need a [mcve]. Short answer - if the `User` is the key or the value in the `MemoryCache` it will prevent garbage collection. If not, it won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are saving the value of a property (string in this case) and not an object itself, so your object will be garbage collected.

Comment: `In this case it should be copied by value and not by reference` This statement is either false or superfluous. Best to remove it.